# Getting protobuf related build errors while doing Bazel build

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel, protobuf-java

I am seeing the following error while doing bazel build. I found this link https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23184. I deleted `protoc-gen-go` from ${GOPATH}/bin. But still I am seeing this error.

```
In file included from external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc:33:
external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_kotlin_generator.h:59:41: error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'
  uint64_t GetSupportedFeatures() const override;
                                        ^
```

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to incompatible c++ compiler in my laptop. This issue is resolved now.